# Return index corresponding to maximum occurrences of a value, looping through every row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two data frames. One of which gives the details of the items in a store. It has columns: item_name and item_id. The other data frame: 'purchase history' has two columns customer_id and item_id. For every item_id in the first dataframe, I need to find the customer that has purchased the item maximum number of times.

The data frames look like below. These are sample data frames. 
My original data frame has around 40,000 rows, so, a generic code will be much appreciated.

**Item Description**

[image: Item Description]

**User Purchase History**
[image: User Purchase History]

**My final output should be like the one below.**
[image: Final_DataFrame]

I have tried looping and adding loops. But I really do not know where to start. Any help to give the final output will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add your data as tables rather than pictures?

Comment: I've edited it some time back, please reload the page and let me know if you're still unable to view it as tables.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use `map` on each row of the second dataframe, applying a function that is able to find the most frequent item inside a list.

```
def max_frequent(x):
     x_list = x.split(',') # create the list of values
return max(set(x_list), key = x_list.count)
#apply the function to the column
df['max_item']=df['item_id'].map(lambda x: most_frequent(x))
```

After that you will know which is the most purchased item by every customer.
It is then strightforward merge the information with `merge` of pandas using `item_id` as the key. You have to rename the columns of the dataframes in order to properly merge the dataframe into one.

**Note**: the code assume that the item_id in the second dataframe is a single string that can be split by `.split` method.

Comment: Hi! As I understand, By this code, I'll get the item purchased the maximum number of times by each customer. But what I need is the other way around. I need for every item id, the customer who has purchased that particular item maximum number of times. I hope you get it. Please have a look at the final output expected to understand better.

Comment: This is the same. If, from the second dataframe, you know which item is the most purchased from a customer, you can infer the other way around. You can add a column where you can put how many items the customer purchased. Then, you can select the customer that bought that specific item the most.

Answer (score 0):

Not very optimal but should do the work:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
c = defaultdict(Counter)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A1",23],["A2",28],["A3",26],["A4",30],["A5",35],["A6",80]],
                    columns=['item_name','item_id'],dtype=str)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["AX89","23,30"],["AX89","23,30"],["AX90","35,80,23,28"],["AX91","26,28"]],
                    columns=['customer_id','item_id'],dtype=str)

for i,r in df2.iterrows():
    items = r['item_id'].split(',')
    for item in items:
        c[item][r['customer_id']] += 1

data = [[k,v.most_common(1)[0][0]] for k,v in c.items()]

data = []
for k,v in c.items():
    max_bought = v.most_common(1)[0][1]
    max_bought_user = [i[0] for i in v.most_common() if i[1] == max_bought]
    data.append([k,','.join(max_bought_user)])

result = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['item_id','max_times_bought_by'],dtype=str)
result = pd.merge(result,df1,how='left',on='item_id')
```

Output:

```
item_id max_times_bought_by item_name
0   23  AX89                A1
1   30  AX89                A4
2   35  AX90                A5
3   80  AX90                A6
4   28  AX90,AX91           A2
5   26  AX91                A3
```

Comment: Hi I'm getting a type error, don't know why. Please help.                                                 ----> 5     data.append([k,','.join(max_bought_user)])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Can you run `print(max_bought_user)`?

Comment: Yes, according to my actual dataframe,I'm getting a list of four integers: [154960, 593439, 1147269, 1433188]

Comment: Hi! Thank you. Got it now. Converted each element in the list to a string. Please suggest if that's the right approach.

Comment: Yes, it is correct since I'm using `str` type for  `customer_id` in my example.